# How difficult is this matching-like problem?

Tags: algorithms, np-hard, matching

Let $A$ and $B$ be two sets of integers with $|A|>|B|$.
Given a map $f: A \rightarrow B$ and $i \in A, j \in B$, let us use the shorthand  "$i$ is matched to $j$" if $f(i)=j$. I am looking to solve
$$ \min_{f: A \rightarrow B} \sum_{j \in B} (\mbox{ number of nodes matched to } j)^2, $$
$$ \mbox{ subject to } |i-f(i)| \leq 2 \mbox{ for all } i \in A. $$

In other words, the function $f$ should not "move" any $i \in A$ too far and should come as close to a matching as possible.

Has something like this been studied before? If so, is it known to be NP-hard, or is there an obvious reduction? Are there any known variations on this (e.g., by changing the cost) that are polynomial-time solvable?

Comment: is it true that every $i \in A$ needs to be matched and that for $i\in A$ it holds that $\exists j: |i-j|\leq 2 \land j\in B$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observing that there exists an optimal solution such that for any $i_1<i_2$ , $f(i_1)\le f(i_2)$ (otherwise, we can swap $f(i_1)$ and $f(i_2)$), there is a dynamic programming algorithm solving your problem.

We sort $A$ and $B$ firstly. Suppose $A=\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$ and $B=\{b_1,\ldots,b_m\}$, where $a_1<\cdots<a_n$ and $b_1<\cdots <b_m$. Let $D(i,j)=\min_{f:\{a_1,\ldots,a_i\}\to\{b_1,\ldots,b_j\}}\sum_{j'\le j}(\text{number of nodes matched to }j')^2$, then $$D(i,j)=\min_k D(i-k,j-1)+k^2,$$
where the minimum is taken over all $k$ such that $a_{i-k}$ is able to be matched to $b_j$. The original objective is to compute $D(n,m)$. It can be done by this recurrence in $O(n^2m)$ time.

Answer (score 0):

There is a variation on the cost function that might achieve similar goals and is polynomial solvable.

Consider the following problem: given sets of integers $A,B$ and a constant $c$, find $f:A \to B$ such that $|i-f(i)| \le 2$ for all $i \in A$, and $|f^{-1}(j)| \le c$ for all $j \in B$ (i.e., each $j \in B$ has at most $c$ nodes matched to it).

This problem can be solved in polynomial time by reduction to network flow.  Build a flow graph with one vertex per element of $A$ or $B$, plus a source $s$ and a sink $t$. Add an edge of capacity 1 from $s$ to each $i \in A$, an edge of capacity 1 from each $i\in A$ to each $j \in B$ with $|i-j|\le 2$, and an edge of capacity $c$ from each $j \in B$ to $t$.  Now use a network flow algorithm to find a maximum flow, and test whether you can find a flow of capacity $|A|$.  Many network flow algorithms guarantee that if such a flow exists, they will find an integral flow.  If such a flow exists, you have found such a function $f$; if none exists, then no function $f$ exists.

You can then use binary search on $c$ to find the minimal $c$ such that such an $f$ exists.

---

What's the connection to your original problem?  Your original problem can be viewed as a $\ell_2$ cost function, whereas my variant can be viewed as having an $\ell_\infty$ cost function.  Any solution with $c$ that is not too much larger than $1$ will be "close" to a matching.